# Poetry cannot install custom script

Tags: python, python-poetry

## Issue

Poetry does not install a custom script (for CLI app)

## My setup

I have a very simple project on MacOS:

```
- .venv
- pyproject.toml
- main.py
- src
   |...
```

Here is my `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry]
...
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
...
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my-cli="main:app"
```

Details:

- I run on MacOS, zsh, python 3.10
- I ran in order:

  - `python -m venv .venv`
  - `pip install poetry`
  - `source .venv/bin/activate`
  - `poetry install`

When I run `poetry install`, my packages get installed in the `.venv`.

I would expect to be able to run `which my-cli`, but I get `my-cli not found`.

When I run `poetry run my-cli`, I get the following error:

```
Warning: 'my-cli' is an entry point defined in pyproject.toml, but it's not installed as a script. You may get improper `sys.argv[0]`.
```

## What I tried

1. Deleting `.venv`, recreating, and install poetry with `pipx` instead of `pip`
2. Changing the `main.py` to something trivial (like simple function to print "Hello World": `def app(): print("Hello World")`)
3. Removing `poetry.lock` and installing again
4. Changing the name of the script in `pyproject.toml` (my-cli to abc...)
5. Removing the `[tool.poetry.scripts]` section, deleting `poetry.lock` and `.venv`, then recreating `.venv`, installing `poetry`, running `poetry install`, then adding `[tool.poetry.scripts]` again, and running `poetry install` again ---> it says `No dependencies to install or update`. This would indicate that the script does not even get considered

Note: that's my first time with poetry

Answer (score 1):

So, changing folder `src` to `my_cli` solves this issue. Thanks to [this](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/2397) Github issue

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> When a script is added or updated, run poetry install to make them available in the project’s virtualenv.

This means you will need to run `poetry install` **after** you add the script again.

[Documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)

Comment: That's what I tried. Just did it again, it shows:

`
Installing dependencies from lock file
No dependencies to install or update
`

Comment: Okay. I'Ve looked at what you've marked as the awnser and that seems to also work.